# I have to extract only those empid from a table whose Status is both A and B only

Tags: sql

I have to extract only those empid from a table whose status is both A and B only.

```
EMPID      Status     Number
1          A          X
1          B          Y
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question/problem?

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data, and also the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to approach this query.  One way is to verify that each employee does *not* have any status other than `A` or `B` associated with him, and that there are two distinct statuses associated with him.  Note that the first condition being true means that the only two distinct statuses present must be `A` and `B`.

```
SELECT EMPID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY EMPID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Status NOT IN ('A', 'B') OR Status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT Status) = 2
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: @raviranjan Make sure that Status column doesnt have `null` if you use this method

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi I slightly updated the logic to handle the possibility of `Status` being `NULL`.